# How do I save all items in a custom ListView and their states on Screen Rotation?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which is being filled by a BaseAdapter.

The items in this ListView are checkboxes and the last item is a TextView and a Button which allow the user to add new checkboxes to this list.  *(Four of these are pre-defined and come from an ArrayList, when the user clicks the button in the list he can add a new item into the list through a DialogBox this new item is also a CheckBox)*

I noticed that when the orientation of the screen is changed, the *new CheckBoxes* and the states of the previous ones are lost.

I read about the Activity life cycle and found how this is happening. I also read about the **onSaveInstanceState** and **onRestoreInstanceState** methods can be used to save information about the activity in a Bundle and later use this to restore everything.

However, I couldn't think of a way to save all the information about the states & text of the old CheckBoxes & the new CheckBoxes and also how would I add the information of my last item which is a TextView and a Button.

Thanks.

Comment: save each `isSelected` property and texts on `onSaveInstanceState` then use them on `onRestoreInstanceState`, creating the new ones and setting each CheckBox accordingly to what you saved/retrieved.
Also, take a loot at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ListFragment instead of a ListView.

Tell the fragment to `setRetainInstance` and then reattach the fragment instead of creating a new one when you switch orientation.

Sam_D is incorrect when he says that you cannot use config changes if you use this method. `getView` is still called normally after which you can restore your listview back to the state you require (assuming you kept hold of your adapter in a private field within the fragment)

Comment: Way better answer than my comment :)

Comment: I'm not using `ListActivity` I'm simply extending a `BaseAdapter` and populating a `ListView` with it. My `Activity` class extends the `ActionBarActivity` class.

Comment: This would not affect your ability to use this method. Simply replace your ListView with a ListFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance in your activity. And in your onCreate() use getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance() for getting the saved objects..

see below code for reference...

```
@Override
        public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
            //stop = true;
           // if (pd != null) pd.dismiss();
            List l = new ArrayList();           
            if(yourColl !=null)
            {
                l.add(rezColl);
            }
            l.add(true); // save boolean
            return l;
        }



and in oncreate() 

List al = (ArrayList) getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
if(al!=null){
   Iterator itr=al.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext())
   {
    try{
    Object o=itr.next();                    
    if(o instanceof ArrayList)
    {
       yourColl=(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>)o;
    }
    if(o instanceof Boolean)
    {
      //do something
    }
     }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`setRetainInstance` can be useful, but I try to never use it for a `Fragment` (or a `ListFragment`) which will expose a `View`. What this does is essentially tell your `Fragment` to ignore configuration changes, such as orientation change (there are many others...), which means you can't take advantage of configuration qualifiers in your resource files for this `Fragment` (for example, having a different layout xml for landscape vs. portrait).

Much better would be to mutate the array that you originally used to populate the adapter whenever a user interacts with the UI (ie checking a checkbox you can represent by a boolean), creating something like a wrapper class for each item. Save that array during `onSaveInstanceState`, and then re-populate your adapter when the `Fragment` restarts. Of course this is a little annoying because your class/array will have to implement the `Parcelable` interface - but an easy way out of having to do that would be to just serialize it into a `String` using the Gson library, and likewise de-serializing it back to an array, also using Gson.

Comment: The ListFragment is most likely used only to display the ListView which would have very little effect on orientation changes as the ListView itself is likely identical in both orientations. The container activity can still amend its layout as normal.

Comment: That may be true, but I'd rather not make (hack) assumptions like that...from what I can tell, the setRetainInstance API is not intended to be used like this.

Comment: It is not an assumption for your own code. If my statement is not true in the project being worked on then of course you cannot do this but otherwise setRetainInstance is a valid choice to overcome the problem this question asks about. Do you have a reference to your claim that it is not intended for use in this way?

Comment: You are assuming that this fragment will never need to use configuration changes, including if you or somebody else reuses this Fragment somewhere else. Being that Fragments are meant to be reused, it doesn't seem wildly unlikely. Have a look at the note at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) regarding best practice. It's not that your option doesn't "work" - it's just not ideal.

Comment: I am assuming nothing. I am offering a possible solution to the stated problem only not a "catch all" solution. Maybe it will be helpful, maybe it won't but that is up to the OP to try and decide. I don't deny that there are also problems with this approach such as leaking contexts but as I said, this was a suggestion that works if handled correctly.

Comment: It seems you made an incorrect assumption. 'setRetainInstance' does not cause configuration changes to be ignored. The fragment still calls 'getView' as normal and loads the layout according to the current configuration. Any variables/fields in the fragment remain intact as expected but it is up to the developer to restore the UI back to the state required.